Checkbox All does not checks all the other checkboxes
I call a UserForm by clicking a button in sheet1. The UserForm is created by the code in Private Sub UserForm_Initialize(). The UserForm contains a frame populated by several checkboxes. One of these checkboxes, named All, intends to select all the other checkboxes. However, when I click it all the other checkboxes remain unchecked.
I coded the events associated with each checkbox click and for the All checkbox, Private Sub All_Click(), I set all other checkboxes values to true which normally should tick them. But it does not work. Any guidance would be more than welcomed.
My code so far:
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim myFrame As MSForms.Frame
    Dim myCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim topPosition As Long
    Dim checkBoxNames As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim txtBox As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim lbl As MSForms.Label
    
    'Set width and height of UserForm SMA
    With Me
        .Width = 270
        .Height = 240
        .ForeColor = &H464646                    'Dark Gray
        .BackColor = &HFFFFFF                    'White
        .BorderColor = &HA9A9A9                  'Light Gray
    End With
        
    'Create the Frame
    Set myFrame = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "SMA", True)
    With myFrame
        .Left = 25
        .Top = 5
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 190
        .Caption = "Select SMA"
        .ForeColor = &H464646                    'Dark Gray
        .BackColor = &HFFFFFF                    'White
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
        .BorderColor = &HA9A9A9                  'Light Gray
    End With
    
    'Define checkbox names
    checkBoxNames = Array("SMA10", "SMA20", "SMA50", "SMA100", "SMA200", "All")
    
    'Initialize top position for checkboxes
    topPosition = 10
    
    'Add checkboxes to the frame
    For i = LBound(checkBoxNames) To UBound(checkBoxNames)
        Set myCheckBox = myFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", checkBoxNames(i), True)
        With myCheckBox
            .Left = 25
            .Top = topPosition
            .Width = 100
            .Height = 20
            .Caption = checkBoxNames(i)
            .AutoSize = True
            .ForeColor = &H464646                'Dark Gray
            .BackColor = &HFFFFFF                'White
        End With
        topPosition = topPosition + 30
    Next i
    
    'Uncheck the checkboxes
    With myFrame
        .SMA10.Value = False
        .SMA20.Value = False
        .SMA50.Value = False
        .SMA100.Value = False
        .SMA200.Value = False
        .All.Value = False
    End With

    'Add textbox for user input
    Set txtBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txtUserChoice", True)
    With txtBox
        .Left = 140
        .Top = 50
        .Height = 20
        .AutoSize = False
        .Font.Size = 10
        .ForeColor = &H464646                    'Dark Gray
        .BackColor = &HFFFFFF                    'White
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
        .BorderColor = &HA9A9A9                  'Light Gray
    End With
    
    'Add label for textbox
    Set lbl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblUserChoice", True)
    With lbl
        .Left = 140
        .Top = 30
        .Caption = "Or enter number of periods:"
        .AutoSize = True
        .WordWrap = False
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
        .Font.Name = ("Arial Narrow")
        .Font.Size = 10
        .ForeColor = &H464646                    'Dark Gray
        .BackColor = &HFFFFFF                    'White
        .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleNone
    End With
    
    'Create OK and Cancel buttons
    Dim btnOK As MSForms.CommandButton
    Dim btnCancel As MSForms.CommandButton
    
    'Create button OK
    Set btnOK = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btnOK", True)
    With btnOK
        '.Name = "btnOK"
        .Left = 150
        .Top = 90
        .Width = 80
        .Height = 25
        .Caption = "OK"
        '.Font = 10
        .Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
        .ForeColor = &H464646                    'Dark Gray
        .BackColor = &HFFFFFF                    'White
        .Enabled = True
    End With
        
    'Create button Cancel
    Set btnCancel = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btnCancel", True)
    With btnCancel
        '.Name = "btnCancel"
        .Left = 150
        .Top = 125
        .Width = 80
        .Height = 25
        .Caption = "Cancel"
        '.Font = 10
        .Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
        .ForeColor = &H464646                    'Dark Gray
        .BackColor = &HFFFFFF                    'White
        .Enabled = True
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub SMA10_Click()
    'Assign value 10 when SMA10 checkbox is checked
    If myFrame.SMA10.Value = True Then
        myFrame.SMA10.Value = 10
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SMA20_Click()
    'Assign value 20 when SMA20 checkbox is checked
    If myFrame.SMA20.Value = True Then
        myFrame.SMA20.Value = 20
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SMA50_Click()
    'Assign value 50 when SMA50 checkbox is checked
    If myFrame.SMA50.Value = True Then
        myFrame.SMA50.Value = 50
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SMA100_Click()
    'Assign value 100 when SMA100 checkbox is checked
    If myFrame.SMA100.Value = True Then
        myFrame.SMA100.Value = 100
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SMA200_Click()
    'Assign value 200 when SMA200 checkbox is checked
    If myFrame.SMA200.Value = True Then
        myFrame.SMA200.Value = 200
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub All_Click()
    'If checkboxAll is checked, set other checkboxes to be checked
    If myFrame.All.Value = True Then
        With myFrame
            .SMA10.Value = True
            .SMA20.Value = True
            .SMA50.Value = True
            .SMA100.Value = True
            .SMA200.Value = True
        End With
        MsgBox "All checkboxes set to True."
    Else
        MsgBox "Checkbox All is not checked."
    End If
End Sub


Click or change events are not triggered when you create userform programmatically. If you create userform manually, they'll work. It'll be faster.
If you want to create userform programmatically anyway, look here: click event not working on programmatically / dynamically created optionbutton

Ho I didin't know that. Thank you for the answer One question out of curiosity: what's then the point of creating a userform programmatically?? In which context is it useful?

Just a guess: if you need a dynamic useform which contents depend on something else (what user did in the document etc.). You can make events work for programmaticaly created userforms too (see the link above), but if your form is not going to change a lot, it's easier to create it manually (making it dynamic looks like an overcomplication to me). Personally, I've never needed a dynamic userform. I'll learn to do it, should the need ever arise.
